# Pointers and tips to create a short answer quiz in Android Studio using Java?

Tags: java, android, database

I am looking for pointers on how to create a short answer quiz in Android Studio Using Java. I would like to have it use questions and answers from a database (which I am not sure how to create). Any tips on how to start, websites, resources, or clips of code would be great! I'm kind of stuck and not sure how to begin, so any help is appreciated! I have checked the Android documentation and done research on various sites, but I am not sure where to start.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Also don't morph your question into several others be continued editing. Questions on SO should be self-contained and about *one* problem (and no "do this whole project" doesn't count as one problem).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few steps to this .

1. Database
2. UI Interface
3. Logic

Create a model class with the Classname(String Question,Array of options, correct option position)

Create an UI to access this database either using recyclerView or a viewPager and assign click listeners to the individual buttons.

The logic is very simple that if the button click corresponds to the correct option position .. the no of correct answers go up and vice versa

Here is a [Github Repo](https://github.com/vkasojhaa/QuizBee-Android)

.
For the error -> this is because from Android Studio uses java 11 from version 4.2 onwards and old code might not run.
Do the suggested fix.
If it doesn't work you need to set your android Studio to use Java 8 instead of java 11.
To do this
Go to
File>> Project Structure >> SDK Location
Then change the JDK location to the place where your java 8 jdk is located.

Comment: Thank you so so much! Please see updated post

Comment: How do I know where the Java 8 JDK location is?

Comment: download the jdk 8 from oracle . it should be in Program Files if you're using a windows.

Comment: I'm so sorry - but I do not know how to do that.. Could you please be more specific? I am using a MacBook, if that helps. I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Click on File> project Structure> change the gradle version to something more recent

Comment: In the post, I included a picture. What should I make the numbers?

Comment: Go to Help and see your android studio version .. The upper value would be the same as your android studio version

Comment: https://youtu.be/JA9s_Fntg_4 here's a youtube video with step by step instructions

Comment: :).. Happy to help..you can upvote and  accept the answer if it helped you so that others having the same problem as you can be benefitted as well.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to upvote yet, but I will as soon as I can!

Comment: I used the youtube tutorial and wrote out the code as well as ran it on a device, but it says I won the game even if I answer all the questions incorrectly. I'm not sure what I did incorrectly, but I will post the code in a separate question.

Comment: It's probably because of the end logic. .. You can add it to this as well